# Hibernate Criteria for inner join full entity class field

Tags: hibernate, criteria-api

My Entity Model Class are

```
------- A -----------
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NameA")
    private String nameA;

    public B getBid() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setBid(B bid) {
        this.b = bid;
    }

    public String getNameA() {
        return nameA;
    }

    public void setNameA(String nameA) {
        this.nameA = nameA;
    }
    @JoinColumn(name = "BID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    private B b;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
--------------------------------------------
------------------ B -----------------------

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NameB")
    private String nameB;


    public String getNameB() {
        return nameB;
    }

    public void setNameB(String nameB) {
        this.nameB = nameB;
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

and 
I want to 
make this Query `session.createQuery("select a.b from A a").list();`

with Criteria API ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have the inverse relationship, and since Criteria doesn't allow selecting another entity than the root entity, you'll have to use a subquery, but it's ugly:

```
DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(A.class, "a");
subquery.createAlias("a.b", "b2");
subquery.setProjection(Projections.property("b2.id"));

Criteria c = session.createCriteria(B.class, "b1");
c.add(Subqueries.propertyIn("b1.id", subquery));
```

If you had the inverse OneToMany relationship from B to A, you would just have to do

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(B.class, "b1");
c.createAlias("b1.as", "a");
```

BTW, these non-dynamically constructed queries are better expressed with HQL than with the criteria API. If your real query is the one you asked, just use HQL: it's more readable and more powerful.

Comment: Your sample and suggestion are good but Do not have another way to do this?For example b.* or b.nameB special field of B class which no mapping Annotation for A class above my sample Model classes

Comment: Not sure I have understood. I gave you the translation of your HQL query: "select a.b from A a". This query returns all the instances of B that are references by at least one instance of A. Is this what you want? If not, what do you want?

Comment: I want to make this only Projections.property or Projectionlist not want to use DetachedCriteria or subquery

Comment: You're telling me how you want to do it, but not what you want to do. What should the request return?

Comment: I dont know How to do that but there can be a way in hibernate.     All fields(Columns in Table B) of B class that is a instance in A Class with ManyToOne?

Comment: Then, AFAIK, my solution is the one you're looking for. It will return instances of B. Call the getters to get the column values. Or add a projection list containing a property projection for each property. As I said in my answer, mapping the inverse association would make it much simpler.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution but I want a optimal solution .Codes with DetachedCriteria that is difficult to read and understand...        Excuse me to borred you